# Popping an alert when changing the drop down entry in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to pop up an alert message when a certain item gets selected in a drop down list in a column of my Google Sheets. After that I want to have two options in the alert message, continue selecting the value or cancel. I think I have to use onEdit() or onChange() functions, but not sure how to use them.

Comment: A couple of screenshots of the spreadsheet, the dropdown list and may be a text of the alert windows wouldn't hurt. Implementation can depend on it.

Answer (score 2):

As a guess. It could be something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Sheet1') return;
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() != 'A1') return;  
  if (e.value != 'a') return;
 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Are you sure?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
}
```

In cell 'A1' is the dropdown list 'a', 'b', 'c'.

[image]

If use selects 'a' it will show the window:

[image]

If user selects 'No' it returns a previous value into 'A1'. If user selects 'Yes' it will put 'a' into 'A1'.